# Dialog is displayed incorrectly in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a Dialog and did the following code, but it does not display correctly on the screen.

```js
batch = new SpriteBatch();
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Viewport view = new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
view.setCamera(camera);
stage=new Stage(view,batch);
Skin skin=new Skin();
FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json");
FileHandle atlasFile = fileHandle.sibling("uiskin.atlas");
skin.addRegions(new TextureAtlas(atlasFile));
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
card=new Card("Hello",skin );
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
card.show(stage);
```

[image]

what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should be more precise about what you expect the output to be; i.e., how does this output differ from what you want?

Comment: The issue is size, yes?  If so, include in your question the output of these vars: `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()`, `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`.

Comment: I want the dialog to be horizontal, not vertical.The same as here:
The same as this dialogue: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D4u-Tsn5g2Q/UtaXze8UAJI/AAAAAAAACHE/KuF07x7Zyq4/s320/Immagine.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your replies, you want the dialog to be horizontal instead of vertical.

LibGDX projects are created run in landscape mode by default and don't rotate when you rotate your phone or tablet. If you haven't changed this, then that's probably why your dialog is showing up sideways. I use `fullUser` in my projects for device rotation.

Edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your android project and set the `screenOrientation` like this:

```
android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
```

You can see all the options available here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: Great, it worked! But can I somehow increase it? The scaleBy method will enlarge the Dialog, but the dialog will not be centered, but offset to the left

Comment: Are you using the LibGDX Dialog or something else? I never use scaleBy and I always set the size directly so I'm not sure how that affects the methods like getHeight and getWidth. But the usual method for centering is to set the x position of the Dialog using Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - dialog.getWidth()/2 and set the y position to Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - dialog.getHeight()/2.